# Zapier scripting without action key

Tags: zapier

Wondering if there's a catch all for actions pre/post functions, I have a certain function I want to run every action through so instead of:

```
TRIGGERKEY1_pre_custom_trigger_fields: function(bundle) {
   function();
}
TRIGGERKEY1_pre_custom_trigger_fields: function(bundle) {
   function();
} 
TRIGGERKEY1_pre_custom_trigger_fields: function(bundle) {
   function();
}
```

I could have something like:

```
pre_custom_trigger_fields: function(bundle) {
   function();
}
```

Searched through the scripting docs and couldn't see anything, tried a few 'guesses' to no avail! Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do it natively - but you could do this:

```
var commonFunc = function(){};
var Zap = {
    TRIGGERKEY1_pre_custom_trigger_fields: commonFunc,
    TRIGGERKEY2_pre_custom_trigger_fields: commonFunc,
    TRIGGERKEY3_pre_custom_trigger_fields: commonFunc
};
```

Should work fine!

Comment: Hey, thanks! At least that keeps things and bit cleaner! Sometimes it's the simplest things! :)